# Getting temporarily locked out of SQLite/MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a sql database on an amazon EC2 instance. I have an app that users can sign into that checks credentials stored in the database. The database also stores payment status information about each user.

If I update the payment status of a single user via my keyboard while shelled into ec2 instance with the "UPDATE" sql string command....

...then the database becomes locked. New incoming "UPDATE" commands from clients are not executed correctly and I can see the database is not updated. However, I am not seeing any errors. It just doesn't update after I manually tweak it.

I tried to reset the database after I manually update it with this python script but it did not work.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('userDataBase.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('begin immediate')
connection.commit()
connection.close()
shutil.copyfile('userDataBase.db', 'userDataBaseBackUp.db')
os.system('mv userDataBase.db oldUserDataBase.db')
os.system('mv userDataBaseBackUp.db userDataBase.db')
```

I am stuck, can anyone help?

Comment: Are you talking about two different databases? "SQLite/MySQL databases" suggests that. Of course `UPDATE`s in one database don't update the data in the other. Either the answer is "What you expect cannot be done (at least out of the box)." or you need to [edit] the question and elaborate.

Comment: Sorry I realize that was confusing. I tried the approiate "UPDATE" command in both SQLite and MySQL. Both become locked after manual "UPDATE"